# iTextSharp does not read pdf with no borders

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext, pdf-reader

Is there any alternative to iTextSharp to read pdf where there are no borders or a way to handle the situation. The library works fine when borders are present.

Thanks.

Comment: Try using Itext7 which is the newer replacement for ItextSharp : https://github.com/itext/itextsharp

Comment: iTextSharp is deprecated and has been replaced by iText7. Perhaps the issues you're having are being solved in there.

Comment: @jdweng thanks will try that

Comment: @LucasHarskamp thanks, will try that and hope the issue is resolved in this library :)

Comment: Whether a PDF has borders or not, does not make a difference for iTextSharp. This is a red herring. For analysis you may want to share example PDFs and illustrate your code reading them.

Comment: @jdweng that's the wrong link, the correct link to iText 7 .NET is https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet

Comment: This question cannot be answered without Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example code, and an example PDF. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Amedee Van Gasse : It is the correct link.  The link I provided is the ITextSharp with the notes indicating is has been superseded by Itext7 and the link to IText7.

Comment: _That_, with the additional comment, is also correct. (By the way I am QA engineer at iText and I wrote that README.md as you can see in the commits).

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse the issue is resolved, will make sure to add example. thanks